# Workout width and heigh for transform scale

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
document.getElementById("wrapper").style.transform = "scale(1, 1)";
```

So the above line of code scales the wrapper div (which covers my whole viewport. Basically the whole page) and scales it.

I'm wondering, how can I work out the width and height of the viewport i'm on and scale it relevant to that?

So if i'm on iPad it will scale my div to the correct size and if i'm on desktop scale it to that size?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure why it wouldn't be easier to just set the width and height to 100%.

Comment: Because I have a button which zooms in and out.. so the div changes @MrLister

Comment: Hm. Can you make a snippet of a jsfiddle or something that demonstrates the issue?